# Show an image without any border using Preview or some other built-in macOS app

Tags: macos, preview, graphics

Here is a simple image viewed in `Preview`.  I need to view only the image itself:  you will notice there is a gray border around it. Especially the border at the bottom should not be present. How can I view really *just* the image and nothing more?

[image]

**Update** the answer proferred by @jmh has the right idea - though not yet an actual working solution.  I rooted around all of the menu items and toolbards for `transparency` and/or `background color` but did not find them.

[image]

Comment: where else have you seen the image without border?  use photos app maybe ? Or safari

Comment: Some apps that can show you images are Safari, (or any browser for that matter), Photos, WhatsApp, Mail, Photoshop, Finder QuickLook, any document editor like Pages, Keynote etc, web services like Google Photos, Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox etc. .. not sure what you need here.

Comment: @ankii The comments from @jmh help clarify the kinds of solutions I am looking for. It is not clear that `Preview` provides them: thus the question to see if I missed something. Often enough features are hidden away that we might not stumble upon.

Comment: I found the transparency setting.  And I also found the place to set the border color and fill color. I updated my answer to show these.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do in Preview is to set the fill color of your image to white.  You may have a border but it will be invisible. If your page color is black, then set the background fill as black too.  You might need to set transparency to 100%.  A little trial and error should determine this part.

It is possible to set the Border color and Fill Color of your image in Preview. Open your image in Preview and go to the View menu item and under this menu, you'll see an option to Show Markup Toolbar. Make sure this is turned on. This will display the 2nd toolbar with the options to set the fill color and to set the border color. See the image below.

[image]

If you click Show Colors on the menu for setting the fill or border color you will get the Color Wheel to select the color. There is also a setting on the Color wheel for Opacity.

Comment: good point. i'll root around in image settings some more

Comment: I looked carefully in all the menus and toolbars and could not find anything about background color and/or transparency. Pls clarify where you saw them ;) thx

Comment: On Mojave its Preview > Preferences then under the "General" tab you should see  "Window background:" with a color picker to the right. I didn't see a way to set transparent however. Note - this sets the background fill of the window when it is larger than the viewed graphic, which I *think* is what the questioner wants.